Using memcmp() to compare signed bytes
I am trying to make a flexible mergesort function for primitive data types like char, byte, int, long etc, where  the fucntion can take an array of any type and sort it by dividing it based on the size provided. The function parameters are:
void mergesort(void* arr, size_t n, size_t size)
where n is the number of elements in the array and size is the size of each member in the array.
I am trying to use memcmp to compare the elements:
memcmp((arr1+i*size),(arr2+j*size),size)
where arr1 and arr2 are pointers to the two divided arrays. While this does work with strings and positive numbers, it gives a problem with negative integers because of the sign bit.
Is there any way I can modify the input or manupulate the bits of input to memcmp so that it can compare with negative integers too?
I do not wish to pass a function as a paramter or use if-else to determine the data type from the size and use different cases for different data types.

I do not wish to pass a function as a paramter [sic] But that's exactly what you need to do if you want to make a generic sorting function.

Passing a pointer to a comparison function is what the standard qsort function does, because there's really no other way to do a generic comparison otherwise. Think for example about sorting an array of structures, where only one member of the structure is relevant for the ordering. If you use memcmp you will use the whole structure, and all of its members plus eventual padding which will contain indeterminate data.

...and in cases where the primary members compare equal you can then decide the order from other members. memcmp() doen't seem to be the right tool for the job when there is an array of struct.

memcmp() also is not the right tool for the job when sorting integers larger than one byte, as the result will depend on byte order, which is likely undesirable.  You're probably on a little-endian machine.  In that case, try sorting a collection of positive ints having a wide range of values, such that they don't all fit in a single byte.

If I want to sort structs, How are you going to archive it without function pointers?

@WeatherVane and others asking about how it will deal with structures... this is purely for primitive datat types: char, byte, int, long....

@Shawn I know, but I am trying to find alternates and trying to keep the sorting job concise within one function

@argo Note your concern is about negative integers, yet char is signed or unsigned, depending on an implementation detail.

"trying to keep the sorting job concise within one function" You can't, but even if you could, it would be a totally wrong thing to do from the software engineering perspective. Separation of concerns is key. A function should do its thing and nothing more. How things are compared has nothing to do with the sorting algorithm, so keeping these things separate is good (and you have no choice anyway).

I started to write an answer, but there is so much missing from this question. What are the exact types you wish to support? Not “etc.“ What is byte; that is not a type the C standard defines. Except for byte and char, which may be signed or unsigned, all the types you list are signed. Do you only want to support signed types? If so, you can simply use memcmp and, if it reports a difference, examine the sign bits and adjust accordingly. Except there are issues of distinguishing types…

… If you support only signed types and only C implementations in which these types have no padding bits, then you can ignore the fact that some of the types may be the same size, because comparing int by its bytes/bits and comparing the same-size long by its bytes/bits would be identical, so the same code works for both/either. If different types may have the same size but different numbers of padding bits, there is a problem, but that is rare, and you might choose not to support it. If there may be unsigned types, they will likely have sizes in common with the signed types…

… and then it is impossible for the routine to make proper comparisons unless it is given some other information to indicate the type. That information could be passed in many ways, including an argument with a code for the type, an argument pointing to a function to perform the comparison, a global variable, or something smuggled in one of the existing arguments (fiddle with otherwise unused bits in addresses). There are also issues about knowing where the sign bit is (big or little endian, and which bit of which byte). So, there are simply too many details missing from this question.

Note C11 §7.24.4 Comparison functions ¶1 which says: The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions memcmp, strcmp, and strncmp is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both interpreted as unsigned char) that differ in the objects being compared.  Note that the comparison treats the values as unsigned char!

Please post the code that reproduces the problem "it gives a problem with negative integers because of the sign bit". What data is passed and what decisions does your program make after calling memcmp?


Is there any way I can modify the input or manupulate the bits of
input to memcmp so that it can compare with negative integers too?

Corresponding signed and unsigned integer types have the same size and consistent representation.  You cannot tell from the representation of an integer alone whether to interpret it as signed or unsigned, and you need to compare differently to sort as signed numbers than you do to sort as unsigned numbers.
You could modify inputs of signed types, type-specifically, so that you can sort them as unsigned numbers, then convert back after sorting.  For type int, that might look like so:
void mergesort_int(int* arr, size_t n) {
    unsigned int *uarr = (unsigned int *)arr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *uarr -= (unsigned int) INT_MIN;
    }

    mergesort(uarr, n, sizeof *uarr);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *uarr += (unsigned int) INT_MIN;
    }
}

But such conversions are type-specific, so you will need one for each supported signed type.  And this is not going to be all in one function, unless that function is a godawful ugly mess.
Additionally, you need to account for byte order.  That could be layered on top of the above as a conversion to and from big-endian byte order, but that only makes the mess worse.

I do not wish to pass a function as a paramter or use if-else to
determine the data type from the size and use different cases for
different data types.

Mick Jagger has some sage advice for you: "You can't always get what you want."
There is a good reason why the standard library's qsort() takes a comparison function as an argument.  Different data types do not have similar enough representation to compare consistently via a single, universal function.  Even restricting to integer types is not sufficient for that.  On a big-endian machine, you might get away with a universal comparison function for unsigned integer types only, but even that does not work on a little-endian machine if you're looking for numeric order.
Passing a comparison function is the cleanest approach I know of.

Or "tap-dancing on land mines...." (Aerosmith). Funny how all that great type information melts away through the const void* (or now const void s[.n]) parameters to memcmp().

Let's say the array is some signed integer type, maybe (0,) 1, 2, 3 ... size bytes long.
memcmp() compares bytes as if they were unsigned, so compare the byte with the sign bit first using signed operations.
For practicality, we'll assume 2's complement.
// Compare 2 arrays as if they were some sort of signed integers.
int arjo_compare(const void* arr1, const void* arr1, size_t size) {
  if (size > 0) {
    const signed char* int1 = arr1;
    const signed char* int2 = arr2;
    #if BIG_ENDIAN
      if (*int1 != *int2) {
        return *int1 - *int2;
      }
      if (size > 0) {
        return memcmp(++int1, ++int2, size - 1);
      }
    #else 
      // TBD code
      // If not Big Endian, we cannot use `memcmp()`.
      // Consider a loop.
    #endif
  }
  return 0;
}


If the array is something else, then need more info from OP.


I do not wish to pass a function as a parameter or use if-else to determine the data type from the size and use different cases for different data types.

Research _Generic so the compare function passed is derive from the types coded and the user does not need to explicitly call it.
